# How to get only 2 decimal places from a function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using a procedure to get some information from my database, and I have a value that I get from a function. That value comes with 5 decimal places, so I tried to get that value with only 2 decimal places doing this:

```
cast([dbo].[myFunction](param1, param2, param3)as decimal(20,2)) as Total
```

The code doesn't give me any error, but it comes with 5 decimal places instead 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we missing some of your logic here? That expression will only ever return a `decimal(20,2)`, which will have 2 decimal places. (Of course we don't know the DDL for `myFunction`, but that doesn't change the statement, as you are explicitly converting the value).

Comment: There's probably something else going on beside this expression, is it part of a `UNION (ALL)` query, for example? Can you post your whole query?

Comment: It's solved, my procedure has a union, and that was without the cast and sql assumes the larger number of decimal places, I had to force in the 2nd part of the union too.

Comment: @HoneyBadger that's correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved, my procedure has a union, and that was without the cast and sql assumes the larger number of decimal places, I had to force in the 2nd part of the union too.

Thank you all.